# WinEdt is saving files under the wrong type

Tags: miktex, winedt

I am using MiKTeX console 4.6, in WinEdt 10.  I believe some setting got accidentally re-set but I have no idea what setting that would be.

Starting yesterday, when I have a TeX document open I can go to File on the upper right in WinEdt, and click "save as" to save that TeX Document file under a new name.  It does that.  The window that pops up gives me an option of "Save as type:" and the value it displays on opening is TeX document, which is indeed what I want, and have always used, and so I leave it alone.

However, (starting yesterday) the saved document looks and acts like it has type DATA.  My File manager identifies it as type 4XX. I can go to "Save as" again in that document, and again specify to save it as a TeX document, and it will.  Then it works as a TeX document.
  
What can I do to get these documents saved as TeX documents in the first place, the way they used to do?

Comment: "has type DATA" how do you know that?

Comment: @user202729 It looks and acts like files with suffix DAT, and when I go to "Save as" in that document, the default suggestion for the type to save it as is DATA.

Comment: So in winedt? Okay... does the issue happen for a new clean TeX file?

Comment: @user202729  I just now tried it on a new document, and that one got saved correctly as a newly named TeX document.  But I have gotten the same error on several pre-existing TeX documents, so it is not just in the one document.